# insert newly constructed element in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I tried to insert a comment before a `<div id="apb">`. The error suggested a workaround, which did indeed work. Was I doing something wrong with BeautifulSoup or is there an error in the BeautifulSoup source? Minimal executable version of my original code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import Comment
soup = BeautifulSoup('<p>This</p>Insert here:***<div id="apb">Stuff</div>')
div = soup.find(id="apb")
comment = Comment('APB section')
div.insert_before(comment)
```

This produces the traceback:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-09e7eb15e6f2> in <module>()
  4 div = soup.find(id="apb")
  5 comment = Comment('APB section')
----> 6 div.insert_before(comment)
  7

C:\Users\bbrown\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.pyc in insert_before(self, predecessor)
353         # are siblings.
354         if isinstance(predecessor, PageElement):
--> 355             predecessor.extract()
356         index = parent.index(self)
357         parent.insert(index, predecessor)

C:\Users\bbrown\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.pyc in extract(self)
232     def extract(self):
233         """Destructively rips this element out of the tree."""
--> 234         if self.parent is not None:
235             del self.parent.contents[self.parent.index(self)]
236

C:\Users\bbrown\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.pyc in __getattr__(self, attr)
673             raise AttributeError(
674                 "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (
--> 675                     self.__class__.__name__, attr))
676
677     def output_ready(self, formatter="minimal"):

AttributeError: 'Comment' object has no attribute 'parent'
```

I am using Python 2.7.  I think I am using beautifulsoup4 v4.3.2; that is the version reported by the Canopy Package Manager, through accessing `BeautifulSoup.__version__` causes an `AttributeError`.

The reason I think the error described previously might be an error in the source code is that I succeeded with a workaround adding 5 lines of code:

```
comment.parent = None
comment.next_sibling = None
comment.next_element = None
comment.previous_sibling = None
comment.previous_element = None
```

I would think that the `Comment` constructor would have set those values to `None` or that the `element.py` code would test for attribute existence rather than testing for equality with `None`. Is the error mine or is it a problem with the BeautifulSoup source?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a related bug:

- [Cannot insert Comment objects without calling setup](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1294315)

Either upgrade to the currently latest `beautifulsoup4` 4.4.1 which contains the fix:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4 --upgrade
```

Or, apply the [workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1294315/comments/1) suggested by Martijn:

```
comment = soup.new_string('APB section', Comment)
div.insert_before(comment)
```